# Arbitrary.. imprecision arithmethics?

Tags: java, math, arbitrary-precision

I'm currently implementing the game server for a little game idea I have in Java. The game will (eventually) deal with very large numbers, say 1e1000 or even bigger, so clearly all primitive datatypes are out since double is only around 1e320ish. So I've tried things like BigDecimal and BigInteger, but these are *way* too slow as I'd like to add/sub/mul (and if possible div [though I could restrict myself to only divide by two, so it can just be bit shifted]) multiple thousand times per second.

I think part of the reason is that BigInt/Dec in Java are immutable so there's way to much copying going around. I have found [a library](https://github.com/bwakell/Huldra/blob/master/src/main/java/org/huldra/math/BigInt.java) that claims to be way faster by doing these operations in place.

However, I am wondering, I don't really need an arbitrary precision library, in fact, I do not care about precision much at all, if the first 5 or 10 digits and the exponent are in the right ballpark, I'm fine.

Is there a way to get a significant speed improvements by trading a lot of precision with really large numbers? If so, are there any pointers on how to achieve this?

I have been thinking about patching for example the linked BigInt library above [so it only deals with the most significant entries in the magnitude array](https://github.com/bwakell/Huldra/blob/master/src/main/java/org/huldra/math/BigInt.java#L71). But I am a) not sure if that is the right way to go, and b) there seems to be a lot of black magic going on in that code.

Comment: What is the largest (1e1000?) and smallest number (1?) you need to deal with?

Comment: Ideally I'd like the exponent to scale almost indefinitely, so the answer to the largest is whatever is possible, the smallest number would indeed be 1, but it wouldn't be a problem to use long/double in the early stages of the game and then switch to imprecise math at some point in the code, say as soon as it goes over 1e300.

Comment: You could write your own arithmetic class for example representing the mantissa by a double and the exponent by a long.

Comment: Note that, internally, Java's BigInteger class makes heavy use of a non-public class called MutableBigInteger. It's source code is available. But I think @Henry has the right idea here.

Comment: What other operations beyond division by 2 do you need? Is there anything beyond simple arithmetic (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`)? If yes, what additional operations do you need?